# MySQL error 1064 on INSERT of DATE

Tags: mysql, date, insert

I have a table named "calendar" that was created with this SQL statement in a PHP program.

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE calendar (
 mdate DATE,
 PRIMARY KEY(mdate),
 special CHAR(20),
 director CHAR(20),
 dealer CHAR(20), 
 meeting CHAR(20))";
```

When I tried to insert data into this table I received an error 1064 from MySQL. In order to determine where the error was, I copied the INSERT statement from my PHP program and used constants instead of variables. This was the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE calendar (mdate, special, director, dealer, meeting) VALUES('2013-05-01','Special Game','Director','Dealer','Meeting');
```

Here is the error message I received:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE calendar (mdate, special, director, dealer, meeting) VALUES('2013-05-01','' at line 1
```

I assume that the error involves the "mdate" column. I tried several formats for the date with no change in the error message. I reviewed the MySQL manual 9.1.3. Date and Time Literals and it appears that YYYY-MM-DD is a valid format for DATE columns. I also checked 9.3. Reserved Words to make sure that none of my column names were reserved words.

I had originally planned to use LOAD DATA INLINE to update my table but it turns out that statement needs FILE authority and the host of my web site was unwilling to grant that authority.

This seems too simple to be a problem. I hope that someone can see something that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You must not use the keyword `TABLE` in the `INSERT` sentence. It should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO calendar (mdate, special, director, dealer, meeting) 
VALUES('2013-05-01','Special Game','Director','Dealer','Meeting');
```

Comment: I knew it was easy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

calendar is already table you dont need to say TABLE

```
    INSERT INTO calendar (mdate, special, director, dealer, meeting) 
    VALUES('2013-05-01','Special Game','Director','Dealer','Meeting');
```